# UITabelViewCell from XIB to be instantiated more times

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a cell template in a XIB that I want to use with separate instances of custom UITableViewCell, with different reuse identifiers. The problem is that dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier reuses cells with same identifier, but I want, instead, to create a new cell each time (in reality I use no more than 4 cells, so that not much memory is wasted). I tried using NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed (Swift), but the returned cell is not correctly shown. It looks like the function doesn't return the cell with right size and alignment inside the UITableView. Is there a way to have 2 separate instances of a cell taken from the same single XIB which have the same characteristic of those returned by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ? I mean, I don't want reused cells but new every time, and with the correct positioning in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of cells as you said that you want to use only four cell then you can just use static cell. Or you also use four custom views of your requirement. There is no need of tableview if you want only four (fixed number of cells) cells.

Comment: Thank you very much for the extremely prompt answer. In the meantime I have found a solution myself. I need the 4 cells in my case, but the solution is easier than it looks. I have a cell defined in a XIB and it had a Reuse Identifier set in the XIB, the identifier prevented the assignment of a new one when I call

Comment: I fixed the problem by just deleting the reuse identifier set to the cell in the XIB. In this way I can dynamically assign the identifier when I call tableView.registerNib and that would fix the problem because I have 2 cells from the same XIB but different reuse identifier.